# Dynamically change background_color in web manifest

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest

So I have an application that allows users to toggle between light and dark mode. I would like to set the `background_color` accordingly when users toggle the theme mode.

For `theme_color`, I can dynamically set the meta tag and put a placeholder value in the `manifest.json`. But as far as I know, there isn't a meta data for `background_color`

Answer (score 3):

There are [discussions](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/975) on the standard of how to support light and dark modes.

Comment: In other words, currently, there is no way to change `background_color` depending on the theme mode then?

Comment: Any update to this?

Answer (score -2):

About IOS part. It's hard code in index.html, So can't changed dynamic.

- first line define app-icon img path

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<path of Icon>">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
```

- second line define the background-color of app-icon

Comment: This is not what I was asking. I was asking how to change the `background_color` which affects the background color of the PWA splash screen.

Comment: OHh u mean hte splash not titleImg sorry.but i guess for ios splash's behavior = titleImage's behavior. I will try it later. my pwa still not adding the splash will do it soon this week. then can discuss with you.